# replace a specific strings from multiple columns in a dataframe

Tags: r

I want to replace the strings `"aa"` and `"aaa"` in the dataframe below with`""`

```
data = data.frame(attr = c(1:4), type1=c('aa','b'), type2=c("aaa", "aa"))

data <- apply(data,2,function(x) gsub("aa",'',x))
```

`gsub` takes every aa and `gsub(c("aa", "aaa"),'',x)` does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data <- apply(data,2,function(x) gsub("aa|aaa","",x))
     attr type1 type2
[1,] "1"  ""    ""   
[2,] "2"  "b"   ""   
[3,] "3"  ""    ""   
[4,] "4"  "b"   ""
```

You could alternatively use

```
data <- apply(data,2,function(x) gsub("a{2,3}","",x))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 dat[2:3] <- lapply(dat[2:3], gsub, pattern = '[a]{2,}', replacement = '')
```

The result:

```
> dat
  attr type1 type2
1    1            
2    2     b      
3    3            
4    4     b
```

Data used:

```
dat <- data.frame(attr = c(1:4), type1 = c('aa','b'), type2 = c("aaa", "aa"))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
data2 = data %>%
  mutate(type1 = recode(type1, "aa" = "", "aaa" = ""),
         type2 = recode(type2, "aa" = "", "aaa" = ""))

attr type1 type2
1    1            
2    2     b      
3    3            
4    4     b
```

if you wanna generalize, taking from @denis answer:

```
data2 = data %>%
  mutate_all(function(x) gsub("aa|aaa","",x))
```

Comment: You should include `library(tidyverse)` or whatever so anyone reading the OP can run your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could just set option `fixed = FALSE` and delete all the a's.

```
data <- as.data.frame(apply(data, 2, function(x) gsub("a",'', x, fixed = FALSE)))
data
#   attr type1 type2
# 1    1            
# 2    2     b      
# 3    3            
# 4    4     b
```